# tensorflow code TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Flag'

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, seq2seq

[image: I have give the mode,but it shows error,run it in tensorflow1.6] 
`BATCH_QUEUE_MAX = 100`

```
self._data_path = data_path
self._vocab = vocab
self._hps = hps
self._single_pass = single_pass

# Initialize a queue of Batches waiting to be used, and a queue of Examples waiting to be batched
self._batch_queue = Queue.Queue(self.BATCH_QUEUE_MAX)
self._example_queue = Queue.Queue(self.BATCH_QUEUE_MAX * self._hps.batch_size)；
```

this code suddenly can't run.Because tensorflow becomes 1.6 version?

[image]

Comment: ,it shows that ValueError: The 'mode' flag must be one of train/eval/decode, but I have provide the arg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API of these Flags changed. Basically, you have to write .value after each instance, e.g. 
`self._hps.batch_size.value`

Comment: there have another problem,               tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('mode', 'train', 'must be one of train/eval/decode') ,when Iwant to run the code ,it shows that ValueError: The 'mode' flag must be one of train/eval/decode,                but I have provide the arg.

Comment: It's the same problem. You want to access the value of the flag, so you have to assess .value of that flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!when I run the code on 'train' mode,It shows that 'SummarizationModel' object has no attribute '_train_op' and 'INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: Attempted to use a closed Session'.Do you know the problem？Does tensorflow1.6 have other changes aboout the train_op or the sess or the supervisior?

Comment: I don't  know the problem. For me it works after applying the changes I described to you. Please open another question for that.

Comment: AttributeError: 'SummarizationModel' object has no attribute '_train_op',now it becomes the error,my code is                              
 with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
      self._train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars), global_step=self.global_step, name='train_step')                                                       'train_op': self._train_op